# Encriptando un texto con RSA en java error al pasar de un BigInteger a un Array

Tags: java, rsa

estoy tratando de encriptar un texto mediante algoritmos basados en RSA en java.

El código me funciona de forma correcta pero hay un momento en el que necesito almacenar los primeros 13 caŕacteres del texto encriptado y no me almacena lo qeu quiero, os adjunto el código y lo que me printe y lo que deberí de printearme:

```
public class codigo_ident extends CRC8{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1){
            System.out.println("Sintaxis: java RSA [tamaño de los primos]");
            args = new String[1];
            args[0] = "1024";
        }
        int tamPrimo = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        RSA rsa = new RSA(tamPrimo); // La clase en la que está el algoritmo
        // LLamada a funciones para recibir valores para las claves pública y privada
        rsa.damep().toString(16).toUpperCase();
        rsa.dameq().toString(16).toUpperCase();
        rsa.damen().toString(16).toUpperCase();
        rsa.damed().toString(16).toUpperCase();
        rsa.damee().toString(16).toUpperCase();        

        // Escribimos en el teclado el texto que se va a encriptar
        System.out.println("Texto a encriptar: ");
        String textoPlano = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
        
        // Se encripta el texto y se guarda aquí
        BigInteger[] textoCifrado = rsa.encripta(textoPlano);

        // Visualizamos el texto encriptado [Almacenar en una variable los primeros 13 carácteres]
        System.out.println("Texto encriptado: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < textoCifrado.length; i++){
            System.out.println(textoCifrado[i].toString(16).toUpperCase());
            if (i != textoCifrado.length - 1){
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

        // Creamos una variable para guardar los 13 primeros carácteres
        String[] firma13String = new String[50];
        for (int i = 0; i<14; i++){
            firma13String[i] = textoCifrado[i].toString(16).toUpperCase();
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(firma13String);

        // Aquí vendría la parte de desencriptarlo pero no es relevante para esto

}
```

Los 13 primeros carácteres de la variable textoCifrado:

```
4B6355E48BBA0
```

Lo que se almacena en la variable firma13String:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@762efe5d
```

¿Alguién sabe porque pasa esto?

Comment: lo que estas imprimiendo es la dirección de memoria donde se guarda el objeto array, intenta con `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firma13String));`

Comment: @Dramaturgo perfecto, muchas gracais